# AWS Auth UI Login - Keyboard Bug

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-mobilehub

In the AWS Auth UI, when I click on username textfield it moves the field out of view. This happens on both Plus and regular sized devices. I am using XCode 9.3 and Swift 4.1.

This is my code below calling the AWSAuthUIViewController.

```
    if !AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().isLoggedIn {
        let config = AWSAuthUIConfiguration()
        config.enableUserPoolsUI = true
        config.backgroundColor = .black
        config.isBackgroundColorFullScreen = true
        config.logoImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "LogoBlack")
        config.canCancel = true

        AWSAuthUIViewController.presentViewController(with: self.navigationController!,
                                                      configuration: config,
                                                      completionHandler: { (provider: AWSSignInProvider, error: Error?) in
                                                        if error != nil {
                                                            print("Error occurred: \(error)")
                                                        } else {
                                                            self.onSignIn()
                                                        }
        })
```

You can view the image of the bug at https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVrkL.jpg - iPhone 8 Plus simulator.

Comment: Where is image ?

Comment: @Paul Marshal, I just updated it. Should be able to see it now.

Comment: I had that issue and many more with aws, I ended up switching to firebase and haven’t had any issues like that.

Comment: @Jake I completely agree with you, firebase is easier to use and understand. That being said, Amazon has lots of interesting services or new ideas and I enjoyed learning how to use some of them but they should definitely not let small bugs like this happen as I cant even configure the AWSAuthUIViewController - it is something they must update.

Comment: One of the things I would recommend is to use the **Debug Hierarchy View** in the Xcode Debug area to locate what the views are called so you could extend or override them.

Comment: @Jake I can't access the views in the Hierarchy as the AWSAuthUIVewController does not allow me to override any views and gives me limited access to it. I wouldn't know where to begin with that.

Comment: Have you looked at [This Page of their Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in-customize.html)

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue - at first I thought it was related to the use of IQKeyboardManagerSwift, but even without it I'm seeing this very same behavior.

Comment: We fixed this issue in 2.6.17 https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2617. Can you upgrade and provide us any feedback on the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this problem crept in with the latest versions of the AWS iOS Swift pods.  If you take a look at the diff of AWSSignInViewController.m from 2.6.13 to 2.6.14 [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/commit/8f5b027c526a411b909b06638bce4d8015cca571#diff-4a940b9910f2f7c52390e4b7deeed679), you'll see that there have been additions to the code for handling the hide/show events of the software keyboard.

TL;DR Just specify version 2.6.13 for all of your AWS pods until Amazon sorts out their UI issues in a later release, like so:

```
pod 'AWSAuthCore', '2.6.13'
pod 'AWSUserPoolsSignIn', '2.6.13'
pod 'AWSAuthUI', '2.6.13'
pod 'AWSPinpoint', '2.6.13'
pod 'AWSCognito', '2.6.13'
pod 'AWSAPIGateway', '2.6.13'
pod 'AWSCognitoIdentityProvider', '2.6.13'
pod 'AWSS3', '2.6.13'
...
```

**Edit:** This has been verified to be resolved in `2.6.17`

Comment: I guess that can work for Pods, for Carthage would it be github "aws/aws-sdk-ios" ~> 2.6.13. Also, this is a temporary fix, not a solution.

Comment: That would work for Carthage, and this could be a permanent fix assuming you never need to use a newer version of the AWS libraries - that's entirely dependent on your project and needs.  That being said, the alternative to this solution is to submit a pull request for aws-sdk-ios on Github and either remove or correct the keyboard hide/show event handlers there yourself and point your Podfile or Cartfile at your fork instead of at a specific version.  Either way you'll need to update your Podfile or Cartfile to use  the newest working version when it is available (if you even need it).

Comment: We fixed this issue in 2.6.17 https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2617. Can you upgrade and provide us any feedback on the issue?

Comment: I've been using 2.6.17 for a while in a custom fork of the aws-sdk-ios repo at https://github.com/hatboysoftware/aws-sdk-ios - I can verify that the problem has been fixed.